# Send HD video over SONET

Tags: video, video-streaming, fiber

In an effort to test our new OC 192 network, we would like to find a way to stream HD video over it for a demonstration. We are looking for a device or combination of devices that connects to HDMI on one side and has a XFP client interface on the other. I understand this is a ridiculous request and we are planning on an "interesting" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a fairly common thing to do in the broadcast/production world.

HD-SDI is the professional standard for HD video (HDMI is mostly consumer type stuff).

[This](http://www.evertz.com/products/catalogue/7707VB-8-HS-OC192.pdf) unit from Evertz in conjunction with an HDMI - HD-SDI converter should do the job. You won't be able to send encrypted (e.g. from a Blu-ray player) content via the converter however due to HDCP.

MRV also have a nice solution for sending HD-SDI over their fibre kit which may be useful.

Comment: I have looked into MRV and Nevion. These both looked promising.